# ASP.NET MVC 4 Routing I just can't figure out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on a project in ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm at a bit of a loss with a particular routing. I have a lot of custom routes already in the project.

I am currently making a bunch of controllers for the frontend of the site (publicly visible part) to be able to do thing like `abc.com/OurSeoFeatures` that gets routed to `/OurSeoFeatures/Index`

Is there any way to do this so that the above would route to something like `/frontend/OurSeoFeature` and another page would route to `/frontend/anotherpage` and also still have my other routes correctly? It seems to me that the above would hit the default route and if I put something like the following it would just catch all the request and would not let me hit anything else.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ImpossibleRoute",
            url: "{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "frontend", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Am I just stuck with making a bunch of controllers? I really don't want to make one controller like `page` and put a  bunch of actions there as I don't think its very pretty. Any Ideas?

Comment: you missed the controller in url , and also in defaults action parameter

Comment: I'm no expert but I believe that the above will direct to frontend controller and then use whatever is in the {action} to route to that action of the frontend

Comment: what routes understand is url object and in url , you haven't specify things for controller in url ... it should be like this ...        url: "frontend/{action}/{id}"

Comment: Hi Vishal, The Above code works. It just will catch all the request and all the other routes are left behind. The controller is specified as the frontend and I don't need to specify it on the URL Parameter. Try it it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you're asking, you simply need to add a route constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Frontend",
    url: "frontend/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "OurSeoFeature", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = "OurSeoFeature|Products" }
);
```

This constraint means the route will only match controllers with the names `OurSeoFeatureController` or `ProductsController`.  Any other controller will trigger the default route.  However, this wouldn't handle redirecting those controllers to `/frontend/...`, if that's what you're after.  Instead, that gets a little more involved.

Firstly, you'll need to create a class that implements `IRouteConstraint`, in order to supply the controller names you want to redirect to `/frontend/...`.  The reason we need this now, is because we'll need to access those names in an `ActionFilter`, and we can't do that if we supply a regex constraint like `constraints: new { controller = "OurSeoFeature|Products"` above.  So, the constraint could look something like this:

```
public class FrontendControllerConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public FrontendControllerConstraint()
    {
        this.ControllerNames = new List<string> { "OurSeoFeature", "Products" }; 
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route,
        string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string value = values[parameterName].ToString();

        return ControllerNames.Contains(value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public List<string> ControllerNames { get; private set; }
}
```

Next up, the action filter could look like this:

```
public class RedirectToFrontendActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        var path = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        var controllersToMatch = new FrontendControllerConstraint().ControllerNames;

        if (controllersToMatch.Contains(controller, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            && path.IndexOf(pathPrefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1)
        {
            filterContext.Result =
                new RedirectToRouteResult(routeName, filterContext.RouteData.Values);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    private string routeName = "Frontend";
    private string pathPrefix = "Frontend";
}
```

Now that we have those in place, all that's left is to wire it all up.  Firstly, the constraint is applied in a slightly different way:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Frontend",
    url: "frontend/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "OurSeoFeature", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = new FrontendControllerConstraint() }
);
```

Finally, you need to add the filter to `FilterConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new RedirectToFrontendActionFilter());
}
```

One warning here is that because I'm checking against `Request.Url.AbsolutePath`, you cannot pass anything in the path that contains the word `frontend`.  So make sure all controllers, actions and route values added to the path, do not contain that.  The reason is that I'm checking for the existence of `/frontend/` in the path, to ensure that the matched controllers will only redirect to that route if they they're not already using it.

There are a lot of added things you could do with that setup, but I don't know your requirements.  As such, you should treat this code simply as a skeleton to get started, making sure to test that it does what you want it to do.

### Updated per comments

I'll leave everything above there, just in case someone finds that useful.  To address what you'd like to do, however, we need a different approach.  Again, we need some route constraints, but the way I see this working is to flip your idea on its head and make the frontend the default route.  Like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Backend",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = "Home|Backend" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Frontend", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { action = "Index|OurSeoFeature" }
);
```

Just as before, I've applied some constraints to get the correct behaviour.  In particular, for this constraint:

```
constraints: new { controller = "Home|Backend" }
```

if you have a lot of controllers that aren't part of the frontend, it might be an idea to implement `IRouteConstraint` to keep a list of the controller names there.  You could even go as far as deriving all of your backend controllers from a base controller, so you can grab all of them with reflection in the `IRouteConstraint` implementation.  Something like this:

```
public BackendController : Controller
{
    // 
}
```

Then:

```
public AdminController : BackendController
{
    //
}
```

Constraint:

```
public class BackendConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    // Get controller names based on types that
    // BackendController
}
```

This same idea also applies to getting the action names of `FrontendController` for the second constraint.  The only thing you need to be careful of here is that you don't have any backend controllers which have the same name as an action on your `FrontendController`, because it will match the wrong route.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the detailed answer. I loved it. Its however not what I was asking (well not completely anyways) I don't want to inlcude that frontend on the url. I simply want to go to `abc.com/ourseofeature` and it routes to `abc.com/frontend/ourseofeature` where the `frontend` is the controller and the `ourseofeature` is the action.

Comment: @hjavaher I've added a different solution.  I think it's what you're after.

Comment: Thank you, The second part was what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the question is over a year old with an accepted answer but the accepted answer involves route constraints when none are necessary. It's really just as simple as:

```
routes.MapRoute("SEO", "OurSeoFeatures",
               new { controller = "frontEnd", action = "OurSeoFeatures"});
```

Answer (score -1):

The basic idea of the route is controller/action.

So if you want to hit the OurSeoFeatures controller's index action then you have to give your route like

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BasicController",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "OurSeoFeatures",action="Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In your case you have left out the controller from your route url. Please specifiy the controller also as part of URL and have a default controller.